# Touchend not firing after touchmove on Nexus 10 (Android 4.2.1)

Tags: android, touch-event

I am using a Nexus 10, and as far as I can remember, touchend events used to fire after touchmove. However this doesn't seem to be the case now. I can capture, touchstart and touchend as expected, also touchmove. However, if I create do a touchmove, the touchend event seems to be cancelled now and not accessed at all. Is this the expected behaviour?